# Redirecting issues when user cannot sign in using Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, devise

In my application I authenticate users using Devise and I noticed that you can change the page that one is redirected to if the sign in fails. On the wiki I found the following example:

```
class CustomFailure < Devise::FailureApp
  def redirect_url
    new_user_session_url(:subdomain => 'secure')
  end

  # You need to override respond to eliminate recall
  def respond
    if http_auth?
      http_auth
    else
      redirect
    end
  end
end
```

Following this example I created my own CustomFailure class(custom_failure.rb) and placed in the helper folder (not sure where to put it). This is the following class I created:

```
class CustomFailure < Devise::FailureApp
  def redirect_url
    new_user_session_url(:subdomain => 'secure')
  end

  # Redirect to root_url
  def respond
    if http_auth?
      http_auth
    else
      root_url
    end
  end
end
```

I also added the following in the config/initializers/devise.rb file (as the wiki states should be done):

```
config.warden do |manager|
  manager.failure_app = CustomFailure
end
```

Although I get no errors, when I incorrectly sign in it still redirects to the /users/sign_in page (not the root page) and nothing is loaded (the page is completely white even though the source is not empty). Is there comthing wrong with my CustomFailure class or maybe it is in the wrong folder?

I am using Rails 3.0.1 and Devise 1.1.rc0.

The wiki where this code is found is at: [How To: Redirect to a specific page when the user can not be authenticated](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-when-the-user-can-not-be-authenticated)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try putting `custom_failure.rb` into you `lib` folder as it is not a helper. Then make sure the file is loaded. Probably you would attempt to load all files in `lib` automatically.

**EDIT**: To achieve an auto loaded lib you would insert the following to your `application.rb`:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

**EDIT2**: you forgot to call `redirect_to` when trying to redirect. At the moment `respond` only returns `root_url`. Try this:

```
def respond
  if http_auth?
    http_auth
  else
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

fyi: the devise-guys also perform this before redirecting:

```
store_location!
flash[:alert] = i18n_message unless flash[:notice]
```

Comment: I rethought your problem. Try my other approach - hope that'll help!

Comment: thank you so much. It works! I didn't add the store_location! bit, should I do that in my 'else' clause before the redirect?

Comment: What if I wanted to redirect when there was an error in registration as well. Is the solution similar?

Comment: You are welcome! Whether you call `store_location!` or not is your decision :] and yeah, you would put it before the redirect. Extending Devise actually is really simple. Either you overwrite the stuff you need or do a monkey-patch. Have a look at the Source-Code. Try `bundle show devise` on your console. You'd probably have a look at `failure_app.rb` to understand what you've done so far. Good luck!

Comment: @NimishJain this post is almost 6 years old. You might check newer API versions of devise: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Comment: If you need `scope` specific behavior in your `CustomFailureApp` you can test `warden_options[:scope] == :admin ? admin_thing() : other_thing()`

Comment: It works. I would now also like it to work not only for my session, but also for my registration. How would I go about that?