# Devise common login page for login and register

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm trying to have a login and register form on one page with devise. But how can I redirect back to the common page when there is an unsuccessful try to login or register? It i being redirected to the appropriate login or register specific page.

Thanks

Comment: Wouldnt a custom failure(like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4180386/redirecting-issues-when-user-cannot-sign-in-using-devise) do the trick? as a validation error on signup just sends you to `:back` i would think. what devise version are you in.

Comment: The version is devise 4.2.0